# Struts 2 Convention Plugin and JSP files under WEB-INF

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

When using Struts2 convention plugin, the plugin automatically forwards a `hello-world.action` request to `/WEB-INF/content/hello-world.jsp` even if  no `HelloWorld.java` is defined.

Please see http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/convention-plugin.html for that.

On the other hand, we put JSP files under WEB-INF to avoid any direct access to JSP files.

I think this behavior of convention plugin ruins JSP access policy. Any one can make a direct access to a JSP by simply calling a, build on the fly, action.

Am I correct?! If yes, can we disable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not quite correct. The pages have not direct access if they are under `WEB-INF`. The convention plugin creates additional to XML based configuration from the `Action` classes by convention. So, you have access only to results returned by those actions. The convention plugin places its configuration under the XWork package as described in the docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14213793/573032) answer. So, resolving conflicts, which is possible if you don't specify a parent package. You can also use convention annotations to customize the generated configuration. The convention plugin by default scans for classes under the base package, which could be `struts` or `actions` that is configurable and have `Action` suffix. These are all default configuration for convention plugin. If you'd like to change the default settings you could use a constant tag in `struts.xml` or corresponding properties in `struts.properties`.

However, the documentation is not clear about how it handles

> *actionless* results  that is identified by the URL

Also, is not clear what URL is used to identify it. I think you are already familiar with actionless configuration, where you can return result SUCCESS without action execution, because the action class is used by default. But, the problem even is not here. The convention plugin along with configuration it creates mentioned above also put an unknown handler which should handle URLs for which a configuration is not exist (i.e. not created by the convention). This is the source of the problem. The plugin also doesn't allow to replace/override the configuration. Happily, there's unknown handler manager (that could be replaced if needed) who is handled unknown actions via iteration of `"unknown-handler-stack"`, that is managed by this manager. With the handler stack you could configure the order in which unknown handlers are iterated. Note, the loop ends when an action config is returned by the handler. This means if you create your own unknown handler and set the order in the stack then convention handler could be bypassed.
.

Comment: I've reviewed your answer and the link, unfortunately I didn't get my answer. According to sample the hello-world.jsp is the result of action, but it is still a jsp which can be access. Let me ask this way, is it possible to configure the convention plugin to not show hello-world.jsp (even if it is a valid result) when calling hello-world.action ! Thanks.

Comment: hello-world action returns a result which is configured by the package based configurator. So, in the `execute` you can return any result. See updated answer.

Comment: Hello and sorry to revive this question, but I'm struggling with the same issue as OP and I can't figure out how to disable this `actionless results` from Struts2 convention plugin, or deal with them to prevent direct access to my `JSP` files. @RomanC I know you're still being active here on stackoverflow so please could you explain your answer better? I've created a cuestion here on this same matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185042/deny-direct-access-to-jsp-files-in-struts2-with-naming-convention-plugin . Thanks in advance