# Deny direct access to JSP files in Struts2 with Naming Convention plugin

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

I've been struggling with this issue as I'm new to Struts2 development, and just started using this naming Convention Plugin recently.

I'm trying to create a simple webapp which at first will only consist in two pages:

1. Login page (`login.jsp`)
2. Home page (`home.jsp`)

First a login page is shown to the user, and if the correct username and password are provided, they log in and get redirected to the home page.

I've successfully managed to create my small webapp, writing down a custom login interceptor and everything's OK and working as expected. I'm able to redirect the user to the login page if he/she tries to call the `HomeAction`( which results in `home.jsp`if you previously logged in) directly like `http://myserver/homeAction`.

Problem comes when I try to access JSPs directly like this:

`http://myserver/home`

As I'm using this `Convention plugin`, Struts fetches my `home.jsp`plugin and displays it. This is not the behaviour I expected, as `home.jsp`should be shown only as a `loginAction` successful result.

**Things I tried to solve this issue**

Well, as far as I googled, putting my JSPs inside `/WEB-INF/`directory should prevent them to be accessed, but it doesn't, as all my JSPs are in `/WEB-INF/content/`.

Another thing I tried was blocking access to any `JSP`resource (blocking `*.JSP` requests). This does the trick as long as you try to access `myserver/home.jsp` , but fails (as expected) when accessing `myserver/home`.

**EDIT:** There's another question in stackoverflow about this issue but I can't understand the answer:
[Struts 2 Convention Plugin and JSP files under WEB-INF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798570/struts-2-convention-plugin-and-jsp-files-under-web-inf)

**INFORMATION UPDATE:** I've found that Struts2 convention plugin uses something called "actionless results" so you can access your `JSPs` inside your `WEB-INF/content`directory by invoking the `JSP` without it's extension and it will deal with it as a dummy action which returns that `JSP` on success. This is an example to illustrate what I'm trying to explain:

If I have `home.jsp` in my `WEB-INF/content`directory and call `http://myserver/home`, Struts2 will "trigger" an action whose result is going to be `home.jsp`. The solution for the problem then is going to be disabling this "actionless" results.

I'll keep updating the question as I head towards the solution if nobody provides an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how d'you  want to disable this feature.

**Create a dummy bean:**

```java
package com.struts.handler;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Result;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandler;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.XWorkException;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.entities.ActionConfig;

/**
 * Created by Roman C on 22.03.2015.
 */
public class MyUnknownHandler implements UnknownHandler {
  @Override
  public ActionConfig handleUnknownAction(String namespace, String actionName) throws XWorkException {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Result handleUnknownResult(ActionContext actionContext, String actionName, ActionConfig actionConfig, String resultCode) throws XWorkException {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Object handleUnknownActionMethod(Object action, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Then configure it in the `struts.xml`:**

```xml
  <bean type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandler" name="handler" class="com.struts.handler.MyUnknownHandler"/>
  <unknown-handler-stack>
    <unknown-handler-ref name="handler"/>
  </unknown-handler-stack>
```

**Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20799404/573032):**

> The convention plugin along with configuration it creates mentioned above also put an unknown handler which should handle URLs for which a configuration is not exist (i.e. not created by the convention). This is the source of the problem.

---

Now putting your own handler will disable convention's one. Thus it will *no* longer handle results by convention.

Comment: Thank you so much Roman, as usual your answer has been helpful. I could disable automatic `actionless result` by `struts2` with that `UnknownHandler` declaration :)