# Struts 2 returns 404 which is not triggered by tomcat error-page

Tags: jsp, tomcat, configuration, struts2, http-status-code-404

Consider struts 2 webapp on Tomcat 7.0.54.

The web.xml is defined as:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/WEB-INF/content/global-error-page.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

This force **all** Tomcat errors (including 404) be redirected to `global-error-page.jsp`;

So if I try `http://foo.com/bad.jsp` or `http://foo.com/bad.ext` Tomcat redirects me to `global-error-page.jsp`

However trying `http://foo.com/bad.action` will still return the 404 error and tomcat can not handle it, is it a way to fix it ?!

Comment: Which servlet version? Maybe it is because of the convention plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **default-action-ref** to catch all the unmatching actions [as described in the docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-ActionDefault):

> Usually, if an action is requested, and the framework can't map the request to an action name, the result will be the usual "404 - Page not found" error. But, if you would prefer that an omnibus action handle any unmatched requests, you can specify a default action. If no other action matches, the default action is used instead.
>
> There are no special requirements for the default action. Each package can have its own default action, but there should only be one default action per namespace.

Simply map its result to the page you want:

```xml
<package...>

    <default-action-ref name="index" />
    
    <action name="index">
        <result>/WEB-INF/content/global-error-page.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad action is handled via implementing `UnknownHandler`. You can configure it in `struts.xml` using a tag.

```
<bean type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandler" name="myhandler" class="org.struts.YourUnknownHandler"/>
```

The class `org.struts.YourUnknownHandler` should implement `UknownHandler` interface to handle the cases:

- when an action configuration is unknown
- when a result cannot be found for an action and result code
- when an action method cannot be found

> Struts 2 can be also configured to handle unknown action or result, even without `default-action-ref` tag it provides a configuration to process such requests. Generally you can use `unknown-handler-stack` tag by the Struts2 xml configuration and reference handlers. You should check that what `com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandler` is provided. If you are using a convention plugin it supplies by default `convention` unknown handler, which could probably handle your action or result.

Read [How to implement your unknown handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29197214/573032).

The method `handleUnknownAction()` should return `ActionConfig`. This config you should build yourself, you can use `ActionConfig.Builder`. You can also build result separately, but if you have a global result

```
<global-results>
  <result name="error">/WEB-INF/content/global-error-page.jsp</result>
</global-results>
```

you can find it in the runtime configuration and add to the newly baked action config.